# A bag with gumballs in the ration $2:3:5$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

A bag initially had blue, red, and purple gumballs in the ration $2 : 3 : 5$. Let $N$ be the number of red gumballs added to the bag, and $2N$ be the number of purple gumballs
added to the bag. How many blue gumballs we need to add in the bag so that the
probability of drawing a blue gumball, a red gumball and a purple gumball is now $\tfrac{1}{6}, \tfrac{2}{6}$, and $\tfrac{3}{6}$ respectively?

Is it strictly less than $N$ or exactly $N$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: This looks impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, half of the gumballs are purple. In the end, half of the gumballs are purple. Therefore half of the added gumballs are purple. The number of blue gumballs added plus the number of red gumballs added must equal the number of purple gumballs added.
$$X+N=2N\implies X=N$$

Comment: $(\color{blue}{20},\color{red}{30},\color{purple}{50}) \to (\color{blue}{23},\color{red}{33},\color{purple}{56})$ is not in ratio $\color{blue}{1},\color{red}{2},\color{purple}{3}$.

Comment: @cosmo5 If $N=-10$ then $(\color{blue}{20},\color{red}{30},\color{purple}{50}) \to (\color{blue}{10},\color{red}{20},\color{purple}{30})$. As you noticed, there is no solution with $N$ positive.